# Counting the number of stars in an image using python

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

I am trying to write a programme in Python which counts the number of stars in an image.

I first catagorised each pixel into four colour categories depending on its RGB value, as seen below. Before catagorising, I grayscaled the image and cropped it as follows: (200:400, 400:600).

```
# variables 
dot = {} # dictionary of data 
h = 150 # starting height 
h2 = 200 #ending height

for row in pixels[h:h2+1]:
    count = 0
    for p in row:
        name = f"{h} {count}"
        if p >= 250: # very bright pixels 
            dot[name] = [h,count, "green"]
        elif p >= 200: # bright 
            dot[name] = [h,count, "red"]
        elif p >= 150: #less bright 
            dot[name] = [h,count, "orange"]
        elif p < 150: # non bright 
            dot[name] = [h,count, "yellow"]
        count += 1
    h +=1
```

At the moment using this dictionary, I try to identify the individual stars by drawing a box around it. I assume that the stars are symmetrical and of diamond shape. I am also looking at pixel by pixel.

```
starboxes = []
single_stars = []

for num in list(dot.keys()):
    
    # info of pixel 
    row = dot[num][0]
    column = dot[num][1]
    colour = dot[num][2]
    
    if colour in ["green","red","orange"] and "199" not in num:
        status = False 
        count = 0 # previous: count = 1
        while status == False:
            if dot[f"{row+count} {column}"][2] in ["green","red","orange"]:
                status = False
                count += 1
                #dot[f"{row+count} {column}"][2] = "yellow"
            elif dot[f"{row+count} {column+1}"][2] in ["green","red","orange"]:
                status = False
                count += 1
                #dot[f"{row+count} {column+1}"][2] = "yellow"
            elif dot[f"{row+count} {column-1}"][2] in ["green","red","orange"]:
                status = False
                count += 1
                #dot[f"{row+count} {column-1}"][2] = "yellow"
            elif dot[f"{row+count} {column}"][2] in ["yellow"]:
                status = True 
            
        length_box = count
        starting_position = row
        ending_position = starting_position + length_box
        
        if length_box > 1: #no single stars
            starboxes.append([starting_position,ending_position,length_box,column])
        elif length_box == 1: # single stars
            single_stars.append([starting_position,ending_position,length_box,column])
```

To count the stars, I count the number of boxes.

I have an issue that the a large star can generate mulitple boxes, so large stars can be overindentified. I don't know how to fix this.

If I plot the dictionary and the boxes data, I get the following image:
The blue boxes represent single stars.

[image: stars and boxes]

One method I tried was to remove boxes that overlapped with other boxes, like below. I couldn't get this code to work.

```
for start,end,length,column in starboxes:
    
    stat = False
    countt = 0
    
    while stat == False:
        #print(countt)
        if (start - 5) < starboxes[countt][0] < (start + 5):
            if (column - 5) < starboxes[countt][3] < (column + 5):
                stat = False
        else:
            stat = True
            new.append([start,end,length,column])
        
        countt += 1
```

Previously I counted by looking at a pixels that are non-yellow. If they are non-yellow, I would add them to the count. If the surrounding pixels of this pixel are also non-yellow, I would turn them yellow to prevent them being identified as a different star. This worked well for non-yellow pixels that are two in a row or two in a column, but not for a larger group of non-yellow pixels.

I appreciate any ideas and thoughts on how to fix my issue.

EDIT:
This is the original input image.
[image]

Comment: Please additionally provide the original input image. Thank you.

Comment: When posting an image, don’t post a screen shot of the image, but rather the original image. We cannot experiment weit processing operations if we don’t have the same data you have. The screen shot shows many pixels for each of the original image’s pixels.